# Determine whether T is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

Determine whether T is a linear transformation. Show your proof.

a) $T$:M2x2 → M2x2, $T(A) = A^T$

b) $T$:$R^2$ → $R^2$, $T(u) = u + (1,1)$

This is what I did for a:

For all A,B in M2x2, $T(A+B) = T(A) + T(B)$

$T(A+B) = (A+B)^T = A^T + B^T = T(A) + T(B)$

For all $c$ in $R$ and $A$ in M2x2, $T(cA) = cT(A)$

$T(cA) = (cA^T) = cA^T = cT(A)$

Therefore, a is a linear transformation.
Is that correct?

I have yet to solve for b because I'm not sure what to do with (1,1).
Do help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For b), take $A=B=(0,0)$.

Then, $T(A+B) = T(0,0) = (1,1)$, but $T(A)+T(B) = (1,1) + (1,1) = (2,2)$.

Therefore, $T$ is not linear.

Comment: oh well I see. by the way, did I do a correctly?

Comment: @Norhafeeza Yes, you did.